# catch statement is executed every time even if element is displayed in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
Receiving no element exception when for below code.
```

I want to Print "Entered the admin block" if adminsearchuserid  is displayed AND if element emailtextbox  displayed then "Entered the LOGIN block"

but my code is showing catch statement even if emailtextbox  is displayed. I dont understand where i am doing mistake

```
Case "User ID":
        try {
            System.out.println("Entered the try block");

            if (adminSearchPo.adminSearchUserId.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Entered the admin block");

            } else if (lpo.emailTextBox.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Entered the LOGIN block");
            }

        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Entered the exception block");
        }    
break;
```

Comment: What does `isDisplayed` return if it is not displayed? False, or an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle each if condition with try/catch.

Let say, as you said emailtextbox is displayed, code is executing line by line and came to

```
    if (adminSearchPo.adminSearchUserId.isDisplayed()) {
```

here element in if condition is not displayed,leads to exception, then it will go to catch. So there is no way to go another if as two if conditions are in try.

Comment: OK .. Thanks for the response ... i kept the second IF  block in catch  and it worked.