# else if statement not executing in Switch

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have if and else if statement in switch statement code is entering switch but when if condition fails throwing exception that if condition  object not  available rather than executing else if condition.

myupassword is not available so i am expecting it to check else if for lapsstextbox and execute the but its not going to else if condition

```
Case "Password":
    System.out.println("Entered password block");
        if (myacctpo.mypassword.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Entered password IF  block");
                myacctpo.mypassword.clear();
                myacctpo.mypassword.sendKeys(value);

            } else if (lpo.lpasstextbox.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Entered password  Else block");
                lpo.lpasstextbox.clear();
                lpo.lpasstextbox.sendKeys(value);

            }
       break;
```

Comment: If `myacctpo.mypassword` is not available, then it's likely that's where the exception is getting thrown. You can't check `.isDisplayed()` on a unavailable element. Please post the full except when you run this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [catch statement is executed every time even if element is displayed in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893414/catch-statement-is-executed-every-time-even-if-element-is-displayed-in-selenium)

Comment: As said @JeffC, you need to handle isDisplayed if element not available see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893414/catch-statement-is-executed-every-time-even-if-element-is-displayed-in-selenium/53897981?noredirect=1#comment94675646_53897981